# Convert code sniplet gotoandstop to if else coondition

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement, action

i just want to ask how can i make a code without needing the code sniplet gotoandstop when clicking button, i want to make if else statement where if he click this called "answerb.btn" he will go to the destined frame.

Well im thinking this code

```
 If (answer.btn = onPress) {
 gotoAndStop(2);
 }
```

But somehow ita wrong code i dont know what code to use for pressing button. Pls enlighten me ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an [event listener](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e54.html). Here is an example of the way you could to this:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //your logic here
    this.gotoAndStop(2);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from one of my projects which required text to be entered into blocks before proceeding, but it used if statements with buttons presses so you could modify it to suit your needs as you wish!

```
stop();
var names:String; 
var id:String;
var supervisor:String;
namein.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT,paramChanged);
idin.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT,paramChanged);
supervisorin.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT,paramChanged);

beginbutton.enabled = false;

function paramChanged(event:TextEvent):void
{
    if (namein.text != "" && idin.text != "" && supervisorin.text != "" && 
        namein.length >=5 && 
        idin.length >=5 && 
        supervisorin.length >=5)//add your other fields here
    {
        beginbutton.enabled = true;
        beginbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  
fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame);
    }
    else
    {
        beginbutton.enabled = false;
        //If something changes that means we now fail the test you will want to disable the button again
    }
}


function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
names = namein.text;
id = idin.text;
supervisor = supervisorin.text;
gotoAndPlay(15);
}
```

Comment: I cannot add a comment to the other users answer, but I really don't understand how this up vote stuff works around here... How did my answer which contains the if statement the OP was looking for lose the original "green check" or whatever? to an answer which again provides an onClick which the OP wanted to get away from?? My answer "may" have lots of "extra" info, however it provides a working examples which the OP can use and modify....

Comment: you made a simple thing too complicated for the question he is asking. ( at least this is my opinion )